# Can't install MongoDB 3.0 on Fedora 22

Tags: mongodb, installation, fedora

I'm trying to install MongoDB 3.0 on Fedora 22. Following the official Mongo documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat/), I have added a `/etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-org-3.0.repo` file containing:

```
[mongodb-org-3.0]
name=MongoDB Repository
baseurl=https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/$releasever/mongodb-org/3.0/x86_64/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```

When I try to install according to the recommended command, I get this result:

```
$ sudo dnf install -y mongodb-org
Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'mongodb-org-3.0' from 'https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/22/mongodb-org/3.0/x86_64/': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried, disabling.
Last metadata expiration check performed 0:03:17 ago on Sun Aug 30 14:28:03 2015.
No package mongodb-org available.
Error: Unable to find a match.
```

What can I do to install the package?

Comment: I haven't used either yum or dnf, but why are you configuring yum and then calling dnf? The instructions you link to are using yum to install the package and not yum.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On fedora 22, the $releasever yields 22.  On RedHat 7, this variable yields 7.

So on fedora 22, the URL will end up being 'https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/22/mongodb-org/3.0/x86_64/' which does not exist as you can see if you were to traverse from /yum/redhat.

I was able to get around this by substituting $releasever with 7 in the .repo file.

NOTE:  Installation seems successful, although the service/systemctl file is not created by the package/manager.  You may still have to manually start mongodb.